# Trying to understand lambda and stream in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to understand Lambdas in Java 8.

Say I have a Person class that looks like this:

```
public class Person implements {
    String name;
    GenderEnum gender;
    int age;
    List<Person> children;
}
```

Now what I want to do is find all persons which are female, that have children that are younger than 10 years old.

Pre java 8 I would do it like this:

```
List<Person> allPersons = somePeople();
List<Person> allFemaleWithChildren = new ArrayList<>();
for(Person p : allPersons) {
    for(Person child : p.getChildren()) {
        if(child.getAge() < 10 && p.getGender() == GenderEnum.Female) {
            allFemaleWithChildren.add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Now allFemaleWithChildren should have what I want.
I have been trying to do the same using streams
I think I need to use some sort of map, filter and reduce

```
allPersons.stream()
//filter females
.filter(p -> p.getGender == GenderEnum.Female)
//get the children
.map(c -> c.getChildren())
//filter the ones that are less than 10 years
.filter(c -> c.getAge() < 10)
//return a list with the result
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But this code does not compile.
What am I missing.

Also, I don't understand what the reduce method can be used for.

The compiler says
`cannot resolve method getAge()`. This is because `c` is apparently a collection and not the items in the collection, which is really what I want.

Comment: What does the compiler say ? And what does the `Person` class implement ?

Comment: The problem seems to be with the last filter method. `c.getYear()` because `c` is a collection and not iterator of the items

Comment: @Duncan done. But its not relevant in my opinion. Anyone that clearly understands this should be able to spot my mistake as I am not doing something right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the moment (once you fix the compilation error) you would be returning a list of Children. Assuming that in your original code you meant to break as soon as you find a children under 10, the equivalent could look like:

```
allPersons.stream()
    //filter females
    .filter(p -> p.getGender() == GenderEnum.Female)
    //only keep females with at least one child < 10
    .filter(f -> f.getChildren().stream()
                    .anyMatch(c -> c.getAge() < 10))
    //return a list with the result
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

And indeed as commented below, you could use a few static imports, add helper methods and refactor the original code to make it more readable:

```
allPersons.stream()
    .filter(this::female)
    .filter(this::hasChildrenUnder10)
    .collect(toList())

//...

private boolean female(Person p) { return p.getGender() == Female; }
private boolean hasChildrenUnder10(Person parent) {
    return parent.getChildren().stream()
                    .anyMatch(c -> c.getAge() < 10));
}
```

Comment: +1 I would still refactor the children filter into its own function and then use a method reference here. Perhaps something like `filter(this::hasChildrenUnderTen)`, just to make the stream more readable in this case.

Comment: A somewhat more concise replacement for `filter(pred).findAny().isPresent` is `anyMatch(pred)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 `for` loops, that means at some point you need another stream. Here when you call `map`, you map your mothers to lists of children. You then carry on as if you had a stream of children, but you have a stream of collections of children actually.